# Is it possible to solve this specific modulo equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

So I have this equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + 20 + 10 + 12 = 384 \pmod{31}$$

Is there any way to calculate $x_1$ and $x_2$ without knowing one of them or is that impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could enumerate the 31 possibilities for $x_1$ and pair them with the appropriate possibilities for $x_2$

Comment: All you will be able to tell is what $x_1+x_2$ is congruent to mod $31$. Not enough info. In fact, even if you knew one of them, that wouldn't be enough to know the other.

Comment: If this is part of a calculation, you may find that knowing $x_1{+}x_2\equiv 1 \bmod 31$ is sufficient.

Comment: Solving $x_1 + x_2$ (modulo 31) is incredible easy $x_1+x_2\equiv 384 - 20 -10-12= 1\pmod {31}$, and that means $x_2 \equiv 1-x_1 \pmod {31}$.  $x_1$ can be congruent to any of $31$ classes and could be any possible integer at all.  $x_2$will be the equivalence $1-x_1\pmod {31}$ and could be any of the infinite integers congruent to that...... I can't help but think you are assuming this problem implies more than it actually does.  There is really nothing strange or surprising about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your equation is equal to
$$x_1+x_2+42=384\pmod{31},$$
and then also equal to
$$x_1+x_2=342 \pmod{31}.$$
Since $342 = 1 \pmod{31},$ the equation you have to solve is
$$\boxed{x_1 + x_2 = 1 \pmod{31}}$$
and that's a very easier one to see clear solutions.